# Use git without config

Tags: git

Is there a way to use `git` without loading any user or system configuration (e.g. either at `/etc/gitconfig` or $HOME/.gitconfig or locally).

Ideally, I'd like something like:

`$ git --no-config commit -m 'commit message'`

The particular use case I'm wanting this for are integration tests which use `git` for certain operations. I don't want a user's git config to interfere with the test.

Comment: You can use matb's answer, or, note that Git has what it calls *plumbing* commands that are meant for script use, and in general, plumbing commands do not depend on configuration settings, so that if your integration tests use plumbing commands instead of user-oriented *porcelain* commands, those settings won't affect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set ENV var `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` to skip reading system configuration ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITCONFIGNOSYSTEMcode)) and `GIT_CONFIG` ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-GITCONFIG)) to use git config file specific to your integration tests.

Comment: This seems to work as long as I also override `$HOME`. For example, `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=1 GIT_CONFIG=/dev/null git commit --allow-empty -m 'test'` still reads from my `$HOME/.gitconfig` but `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=1 GIT_CONFIG=/dev/null HOME=/dev/null git commit --allow-empty -m 'test'` does not. This looks okay to do. Thanks.

Comment: That's interesting! You might be able to set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` as a less invasive option (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES). I'm looking at current latest git release (2.12), so it might be different for the version you're using ;)

Comment: It looks like as of 2021 (or earlier), `GIT_CONFIG` is only used by the `git config` command. To override `$HOME/.gitconfig`, you can instead set `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/dev/null` ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-GITCONFIGGLOBAL))

Comment: Just using `HOME=/dev/null` seems to work for me.

Comment: Using `HOME=/dev/null` broke a project configuration settings using home variable e.g. `core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/myCustomSSHid"`. One possible workaround is using expanded path e.g. `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/myCustomSSHid"`, which will expand $HOME when writing the setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line argument to override preset config values, see [git -c name=value ...](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt)

It has to be used before the subcommand, e.g.

```
git -c user.name=NotMe -c user.email=not@me.com am 0001_fancy_patch
```